# How to store relational fields to the database?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I've been searching for this for a week now, and still don't find any satisfying answer. If we make any type of relationship to other model in Odoo (in any framework as well) it won't store the data inside it, it will only store its id. Now when the related model get changed, the change will also true for all the child models that's inheriting it.

I want just like in the Sale module, when I change any product in Products model, it doesn't change the same product that's already stored in the orders. Please, any help, I'm very new here to Odoo I used to develop with Java.

Comment: An order correspond to the model named sale.order which is in one2many relationship with the model sale.order.line (SOL). one SOL has it s OWN fields for price, vat... which computation is based on the current state of product at the time of the customer order. That's why the order and its SOL are not updated when the corresponding product attributes (price...) are changed....

Answer (score 0):

An order correspond to the model named sale.order which is in one2many relationship with the model sale.order.line (SOL). one SOL has it s OWN fields for price, vat... which are computed bases on the current state of product at the time of the customer order. That's why the order and its SOL are not updated when the corresponding product attributes (price...) are changed...

In Odoo : an inherited python class EXTENDS the original class (similar to java extends) : in the sale_coupon module, the model located at src/odoo/addons/sale_coupon/models/sale_order.py is :

```
  class SaleOrder(models.Model):
      _inherit = "sale.order"
```

extends the source class SaleOrder defined in the module sale : src/odoo/addons/sale/models/sale.py:

```
  class SaleOrder(models.Model):
      name = "sale.order"
```

That's mean that the inherited class SaleOrder (_inherit) gets the specific attributes (fields) and methods (def) provided and defined in its source(s) class(es) : saleOrder :

```
   origin = fields.Char(string='Source Document', help="Reference of the document that generated this sales order request.")

   def _amount_all(self):
    """ Compute the total amounts of the SO."""
    for order in self:
        amount_untaxed = amount_tax = 0.0
        for line in order.order_line:
            amount_untaxed += line.price_subtotal
            amount_tax += line.price_tax
        ...
```

And you can add new fields and new methods in your inherited class SaleOrder scope :

```
    reward_amount = fields.Float(compute='_compute_reward_total')
   
    def action_confirm(self):
       self.generated_coupon_ids.write({'state': 'new'})
       ...
       return super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()
```

But, you don t need to instantiate theses Classes in your code (you don t need to create yourself Objects).

Theses classes have the basic CRUD-methods provided from models.Model: def create(), def read(), def write(), def unlink()

The source and the inherited class(es) both are connected to the same database-table : sale_order

So one Class-record (python in Odoo) :

```
  self.env['sale.order'].browse(12)
```

corresponds to one record in the database-table : sale_order

Theses classes (SaleOrder) have the CRUD-methods from model.Model : def create(), def read(), def write(), def unlink() and they can override them in their own scope, where you can optionally call the "parent"-def : super(SaleOrder, self).unlink() :

```
def unlink(self):
    for order in self:
        if order.state not in ('draft', 'cancel'):
            raise UserError(_('You can not delete a sent quotation or a confirmed sales order. You must first cancel it.'))
    return super(SaleOrder, self).unlink()
```

Relations betweens models are defined using fields :

A relation between the sale.order model and the res.partner model (contact) is created using fields.Many2one:

```
   class SaleOrder(models.Model):  
      ...
      partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
```

which is reflected in the corresponding database-table.

Comment: I appreaciate your thorough answer but I think that's not what I'm looking for... I'm looking for a way to store our relational fields (o2m,m2o,m2m) to the database, so simply said I want to only get the data and store it to our own model independently. I once read we can use related field in Odoo from the relational field and compute its data one by one but I think it's quite long winded.

Comment: So you have to create your own module : ./odoo-bin scaffold your_module_name addons/  ... And then create your own model : class MyModel(models.Model)... and then import your Excel-data by extending the basic import function...

Comment: That's nothing related to my problem :')

Comment: So it seems you should make your problem clear, so that we can answer accordingly please

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you change the product details It will these details will change accordingly in the sale order after you refresh, about store the id of relation field its the standard way to use,

but there Is another way I think this is the way you looking for which Is store data as a JSON in column with type JSON as an example for sale order line table if you want to store the product as a JSON column it will be like below:
[{"id": 1, "name": "product 1"},]
of course, there Is a way to read and update and create the data into a JSON column you can read about It.

one more way as an example if you want to store the product to the current record of relation table not just store the Id and query to get the result you can just create new fields for data you want to store like if you want to store the name and price with name and id then you must add fields for this date and when you create in order line rather than add just product Id as a relation just add the product data to the new fields you have added before but this is not a good way.

I hope I understand your question and this answer helps you.